# How to get data from docker container into shared folder at host?

Tags: macos, docker, terminal, web-deployment, docker-compose

i was able to mount volume between `~/share` at my mac/host and `opt/abc` inside container. However upon doing so both appeared empty. Even though container had whole app in it. But it worked i created files and it showed up on both places.

What can i do to kind of fetch all file from the container and put it into the folder at the side of host/mac.

Again. It connects and sync on fine from point onward. But stuff already present there inside container isn't not showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you [mount a host directory as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume):

> If the path `/opt/abc` already exists inside the container’s image, the `~/share` mount overlays but does not remove the pre-existing content.
>   Once the mount is removed, the content is accessible again. This is consistent with the expected behavior of the mount command.

"overlays but does not remove the pre-existing content" means the pre-existing content becomes invisible for the duration of the mount.

So for the container folder to appear empty is the expected behavior (when you mount over it an host folder initially empty)

> how to get data into host from container.

You actually need the opposite: get that data on your host first, *then* launch your container and mount that host folder as a volume.

Comment: great answer. Is there a way to connect to existing files. i want to edit the existing files in container from sublimetext. if it hides then that's not possible.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer you would need to have that container folder locally first, before mounting the local host folder to your container.

Comment: is doing git push inside container and then pull there a good strategy, i feel this and copy pasting files might just create duplicates

Comment: @MuhammadUmer if it is done within the host mounted folder, then git push/pull will directly work on host files, without duplication. If it is done elsewhere in the container, again no duplication: those files are kept within the container filesystem, but they will disappear when the container is removed.

Comment: actually i cant since git file doesnt exist in folder

Comment: @MuhammadUmer sure but that was not the initial question. Could you ask a new one detailling your need for git (and accepting this one)?

Comment: i am asking how to get data into host from container. answer says it's expected behavior for it to disappear. Which is great to know and help explain things, but original question is still there.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer OK, I have edited the answer accordingly.